# Does mpi4py have a functioning mprobe (improbe)?

Tags: python, mpi, mpi4py

You can see [here](https://github.com/erdc-cm/mpi4py/blob/master/src/MPI/Comm.pyx#L1179) that `mpi4py` appears to have defined `mprobe` and `improbe`, however, there appears to be no `mrecv`, `Mrecv` or any other variation similar to it. What am I supposed to use to receive the message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matched receives are available as methods `recv` and `irecv` of the `Message` object returned by the message probes - see [here](https://github.com/erdc-cm/mpi4py/blob/master/src/MPI/Message.pyx#L120). This actually makes sense since both `MPI_Mrecv` and `MPI_Imrecv` take a message handle as argument and not a communicator one, therefore they should not share the same class with the communicator-bound calls.

Comment: Thanks. This helps narrow down the problem I've been having. I believe now has to do with the fact the cluster I'm using uses OpenMPI 1.6.5 and an older version of mpi4py. I'm using 1.10.2. Messaging works on my machine like I would expect, but not the cluster. Nor does it work if I switch my comp to 1.6.5.

Comment: Open MPI 1.6.x only supports MPI-2.2. Matched probes and receives were introduced in MPI-3.0.